# Copy one folder into another directory in commend prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, copy-paste, robocopy

I want to copy one folder into another directory with all content on Windows 10. I used :

```
xcopy "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder1" "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder2"  /E /C /I /Y
```

this :

```
xcopy "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder1" "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder2\"  /E /C /I /Y
```

and :

```
robocopy"C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder1" "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder2" /COPYALL /E`
```

but it only copy files which are in this directory and move it to another.

My goal is like we could right-click on mouse on folder and "copy" then "paste" it into another dir.

What is an issue into my commend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so what you want is folder1 to be created in folder2 (was not clear to me reading the question)

So try:

```
xcopy "...\XX\XXX\folder1" "..\XX\XXX\folder2\folder1" /cheirky
```

No need to create folder2\folder1, /I flag makes it for you

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions about this.

1) create new folder in destination directory:

```
md "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder2\folder1"
```

then, copy files from folder1 into new directory folder:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder1" "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder2\folder1"  /E /C /I /Y
```

2) use PowerShell on Windows 10:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder1" -Destination "C:\Users\X\Desktop\projects\XX\XXX\folder2" -recurse -Force
```